# Notepad++ Other locations for User Defined Language?

Tags: notepad++, colors

Back a few years ago I added LESS to NPP. I don't remember where or how I added it. I want to change the colors but I can't find where they are defined in the first place. In the C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\ folder I have a color scheme XML that I added, but this was for all NPP languages, and does not include LESS, and there are no other XML files that have it defined that I can see. It is not available in the `Settings > Style Configurator` Dialog. I can change the colors in the `Language > Define your Language...` Dialog, but, again, this is not where the colors are defined to start with since they are all "Black on White" in the Dialog where they are showing muted blue/green/black on beige when you read the file.

I can override the colors in the `Define your Language...` Dialog, but I feel like it is already defined somewhere and I want to edit that file instead.

Comment: Try looking in the plugins subdirectory

Comment: To clarify things, you might want to edit your question to include what your theme is (Style Configurator: Select Theme), and add screenshots of what you see in your LESS file for the existing colors.  If those contradict my answer below, I will do more research and edit my answer to better suit what you're really seeing.

Comment: @DavidPostill♦ - All I see in the /plugins/ are files for the installed plugins like spellcheck, FingerText, etc. and XMLs of keywords to languages in the APIs folder. BUT, I did find a DLL in the NppExport that I cant read which reminded me that at one time I tried to export the settings from a previous NPP back like 5 years ago. I dont remember succeeding, but I might have. Do you think this DLL would have a UDL from a previous build? but not accessible through the UDL Wizard?

Comment: @PeterCJ - I changed the colors in the UDL Wizard so that I could read the code enough to get by until I found where it was defined previously. (So, the screenshots would only show what I have now, a "Band-aid fix" and not what I was originally seeing (Black on White showing in the Wizard but nothing close to the muted blues and grays I was seeing) BUT... in your answer I might have found the issue, if I understand what you are saying: You did NOT have a LESS UDL previous to this discussion and you were getting similar colors to mine? if so, then, I dont have LESS defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The right place to set colors for your user-defined-language *is* in **Language > Define your language...**

From my experiments, UDL inherits some of the defaults from **Style Configurator** -- including "Global Styles > Current Line Background Color", which defines what the active line looks like -- though it only pays attention to the "background" setting for that one; and if you only have one line in the file, it will look like that "current line background color", rather than what's set in the UDL.  From what I can tell, UDL doesn't have a setting to override the active-line colors, so it may cause some confusion in that regard.

But if I create a brand-new UDL called "LESS", and don't apply any new settings, the active line of text is a black (set from UDL > Default Style) on muted blue (set from Style Configurator > Global Styles > Current Line Background Color).  Any other lines are black on white (set from the UDL > Default Style)

In v7.6.3 and earlier, all UDL information -- names and colors -- are in the `userDefineLang.xml` (usually in `%AppData%\notepad++`).  In v7.6.4, the [release notes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.4.html) link to this [Community Forum post](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17072/new-enhancement-for-user-defined-language-system) by the developer, which explains there is a new **userDefineLangs\** subdirectory which can hold any number of .xml files, all of which can contain user defined languages (which makes it easier to copy or import a UDL from someone else).